# Unable to add list items in item-list.html.twig

Tags: 8

I need to display some links in a list and I'm using **item_list** theme for this:

```
$ii = array(
  'id-1' => array('name' => 'name1', 'class' => 'class-1'),
  'id-2' => array('name' => 'name2', 'class' => 'class-2'),
);
$iii = array(); 
foreach ($ii as $key => $value) {
  $iii[] = array('#value' => '<a class="'.$key.'" href="http://test.com">'.$value['name'].'</a>', '#wrapper_attributes' => array('class' => 'class-id'));
}

$aa = array(
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#items' => $iii, //list of items to be displayed
  '#list_type' => 'ul',
);
print_r(drupal_render($aa)->__toString());
```

But on running this, I got an output of:

```
<div class="item-list"><ul><li class="class-id"></li><li class="class-id"></li></ul></div>
```

where `<li>` tags are empty and 2 empty bullets are displayed on the front-end.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Btw. You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of `drupal_render()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as #value, you want #markup instead, There are also better ways to create links, although I'm not 100% sure right now if you can provide #wrapper_attributes then, but you can call getRenderable() on the link, then you get a render array and should be able to it on that.:

```
\Drupal\Core\Link::fromTextAndUrl($value['name'], \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri('http://test.com'))
```